# Attribute name "p:autofocus" associated with an element type "h:inputText" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: html, jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2, passthrough-attributes

Seems that there is an bug using some HTML 5 attributes using the `passthrough` namespace, i.e:

```
<h:inputText id="text1" p:autofocus p:placeholder="this is a placeholder text"></h:inputText>
```

When I try to run the page in Glassfish I get this error:

```
Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 19] Attribute name "p:autofocus" associated with an element type "h:inputText" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

Notice the placeholder attribute works fine, just the ones that doesn't need to specify a value (`=""`), for example `autofocus` are failing.

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is caused by the [XHTML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.5):

> XML does not support attribute minimization. Attribute-value pairs
>   must be written in full. Attribute names such as compact and checked
>   cannot occur in elements without their value being specified.

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp

> Differences Between HTML and XHTML
>
> In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the autofocus
>   attribute must be defined as `<input autofocus="autofocus" />`.